# How can I access the trusted certificates in the operating system trust store from the browser/javascript?

Tags: x509

I would like to verify a digital signature. I know which CA has created the signature. I need to know whether this CA is trusted in order to check whether the signature is valid or not. All of this has to happen within the browser.

How can I ask the operating system which CA certificates are trusted on the computer?

Comment: Patrick, are you asking and answering yourself?

Comment: @Crypt32 I asked the question and realised a few minutes later it was a duplicate. so I attempted to close it with the duplicate linked. However I can't do that, I can only vote for it